# Ruby mechanize keep redirecting to the original login page

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I try to login to the website using Ruby mechanize. Seems like I could successfully login but when I try to access to the page after login, I am redirected to the original page.

Login page url:
https://sample/login.aspx

Main page url:
https://sample/report.aspx

Login page source:

```
<input name="UserName" type="text" id="UserName" class="txtLoginId" />
<input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" class="txtPassword" />
<input type="submit" name="LoginButton" value="Login" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions" id="LoginButton" />
```

Code

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
agent.redirect_ok = true

page = agent.get('https://sample/login.aspx')
form = page.form_with(:action => './login.aspx')
form.field_with(:name => 'UserName').value = 'User1'
form.field_with(:name => 'Password').value = 'Testpass'
form.submit
page2 = agent.get('https://sample/report.aspx')
```

Line 9 gives me 200 response. However in Line 10 I get 302 response and the content for page2 is original login page though I could access to main page through the browser after login. What could be wrong?

Comment: can you turn redirect off and see what you get? Might give insight into what's wrong.

`agent.redirect_ok = false`

Comment: That's one of those .NET forms, you have to set the __EVENTARGUMENT and __EVENTTARGET (among other things probably). Inspect the request your browser makes to see what needs to get sent.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that `login.aspx` redirects to `report.aspx` after successful login, then you can achieve this in the following way:

```
page = agent.get('https://sample/login.aspx')
page2 = page.form_with(:action => './login.aspx') do |form|
  form.field_with(:name => 'UserName').value = 'User1'
  form.field_with(:name => 'Password').value = 'Testpass'
end.submit

pp page2
```

Here `page2` should be the page with link 'https://sample/report.aspx'

Comment: No, it's actually more complicated than this.